# Max Date on PalmOS

Tags: date, max, palm-os

I have a customer that still has an application running on PalmOS.

What is the maximum date value for PalmOS?

Comment: Is that still around? Sure the max date isn't already in the past? ;)

Answer (score 1):

`PalmOS` *maximum date* is **2040** year. So, don't worry :)

Comment: OMG. Somebody just upvoted my answer. It's 2021 :-OOOO